# How can I manage weird fonts in my website?

Tags: python, html, fonts, discord.py

So I am a discord bot developer, and i made a transcript for ticket messages.
But if the user has a weird name like `Δεαθ`, it gives me this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5545-5548: character maps to <undefined>
```

so is there a way to allow the website to accept various types of fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Printable ASCII characters have no issues in such cases so what you can do is take a supported character and replace all the unsupported character and when ticket messages re sent, include the discord ID of that particular user too.